# tangent vector is zero iff flow has fixed point

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a vector field and $F:\mathbb{R}\times M\to M$ be its flow. I'm trying to understand why $X_p=0$ is equivalent to $F_t(p)=p$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I understand that if $F_t(p)=p$ then differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ and evaluating at $(0,p)$ gives $X_p=0$. But what about the converse? Supposing that $X_p=0$ we have that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(0,p)=0$. But this doesn't show that $F$ is independent of $t$ when $p$ is fixed. As in $g^\prime(0)=0$ doesn't mean $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$t \mapsto F_t(p)$ is an integral curve for $X$  (i.e. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,p) = X(F_t(p))$ for all $t$ with $p$ fixed) with the initial condition $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(0,p) =0$. If $X$ is sufficiently smooth, such an integral curve is uniquely determined by it's initial value (this comes from the the uniqueness part of the theorem about existencse and uniqueness for ordinary differential equations). Since $c(t)= p$ solves this equation it must be true for $F(t,p)$, too.

Your example with $g$ ignores the fact that in a differential equation a derivative is prescribed for every $t$, not only for  $t = 0$, that is the correct example is $g(0)=0$ and $g^\prime(t)=0 \forall t$, for which $g(t)=0$ readily follows.